# What is the difference between pair and couple?

Tags: meaning

I think "pair" suggests complementarity. In carpentry, if two pieces of timber relate to one another as "right" and "left" or "mortice" and "tenon" they are a pair, as well as being a couple of pieces of timber. I would not pay for a couple of shoes unless I could verify that they were a "pair." But with regard to people, one does not speak of a married pair.

Comment: Like most duals, they're pretty irregular. _Pair_ and _couple_ both occur in a number of idioms: _a couple/pair of aces, a nice pair/couple, two pair, a couple/pair of idiots, they're an interesting couple/pair, I'll be there in a couple/*pair of minutes_. There probably isn't a single core distinction that sets them apart.

Comment: I don't have the technical terms, or the sources, but I think _couple_ on its own connotes both two and complementarity, similar to _pair_. On the other hand, _couple of something_ doesn't have this connotation -- _a couple of shoes_ could imply any number of shoes. However, this still doesn't address why _married couple_ works while _married pair_ does not.

Answer (score 0):

In mathematics, pair indicates a set of two elements where the order has not importance: {a,b} and {b,a} are the same sets. In couple the order matters: (a,b) is not the same (b,a).

I admit couple is not quite used in mathematics in English (but [couple/doublet](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Couple_(math%C3%A9matiques)) is used in French). However, there are rare mentions associating the word couple to 2-uple:

- [A couple is a tuple containing only two elements. This creates a couple containing the arguments passed to it](http://pyth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spec_seq.html)
- [Wikipedia: Names for tuples of specific lengths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#Names_for_tuples_of_specific_lengths): Tuple Length: 2; Name:  double; Alternative names: *couple* / (ordered) pair / dual / twin / product

You can find a couple (not a pair) of more differences in [What is the difference between couple and pair?](http://the-difference-between.com/pair/couple)

Comment: Your link is unhelpful as it says that the two words are synonyms and then proceeds to give various usages where the two not interchangeable. The mathematics is also misleading. Order doesn't matter for sets. When the order matters, the term of art is ***ordered** pair* or *2-tuple*. The ordered pair (a,b) has the formal definition of {{a},{a,b}}.

Comment: @deadrat I used "set" in the generic sense. There are ordered sets, partially, totally, etc. Couple is used for 2-uple.

Comment: And there are well-ordered sets and multisets, but they all require additional definitions, so a set in the "generic" sense is the entity defined by a membership function. And, no, *couple* is not used for a 2-tuple, the synonym for which is *ordered pair*.  A trip to the google should convince you of this.

Comment: @deadrat I have biased, couple is used in French. However, couple seems to be used, albeit rarely: ["A couple is a tuple containing only two elements. This creates a couple containing the arguments passed to it."](http://pyth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spec_seq.html) ; [2 double couple / (ordered) pair / dual / twin / product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#Names_for_tuples_of_specific_lengths)